# CSS float. Is it possible to break flow?

Tags: css, layout, html

On my html page I have this situation:

`<div1><div2><div3><div4><div5><div6><div7><div8><div9`>...

Just left floating divs shown one after another. All of them have CSS style **float:left**

I would like to achieve this result:

```
<div1><div2>
<div3><div4><div5><div6><div7>
<div8><div9>...
```

Basically, I would like to break flow on div3 and div8 (or on any div I wish) by telling it to start in new line. All other elements should follow after div that goes into new line. I tried using **clear:left** or **clear:left** on div3 or div8 , but it didn't work. Div would go to new line, but all others would remain where they were, producing undesired result:

```
<div1><div2><div4><div5><div6><div7><div9>
<div3>
<div8>...
```

Is there any nice and simple solution here? Thanks.

Comment: you could put wrapper divs around your three groups of content divs. float the content left and clear the wrapper divs.

Comment: To be honest putting clear:left on div3 should have worked, there is something different about your actual markup and what you've posted here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the love of god... don't introduce any additional `divs` into your markup. `clear:left` works, if your design is correct. (you do know HTML has a whole selection of block-level elements to choose from) Using them might make your targeting a little easier...

CSS

```
div {
    float:left;
    margin-right:2ex;
    width:3em;
}

#div3, #div8 {
    clear:left;
}
```

HTML

```
<div>1</div><div>2</div>
<div id="div3">3</div><div>4</div><div>5</div><div>6</div><div>7</div>
<div id="div8">8</div><div>9</div>
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/d68pr/

**EDIT**
Here's one that doesn't require any IDs, classes, OR extra `div-itus`

```
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>
<div>9</div>

div:nth-child(3), div:nth-child(8) {
    clear:left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TMxSE/

** warning ** `nth-child` may not be available in some browsers. Check your traffic statistics to be sure IE8, and below are a very small percentage of your user-base. Or that those users' experiences are acceptable.

Comment: Finally another answer with common sense. Rereading the OP's post there is something wrong with his design, what he did should have worked as it's essentially what both your answer and mine says to do.

Comment: Should note nth child won't work in IE8 and earlier, just so the OP knows.

Comment: Nice answer! Might want to add a caveat that the nth-child wont work in IE8 and below and might need a polyfill (not that i recommend to use one).

Comment: Simple and works!

Answer (score 2):

I would try this:

```
<div1><div2>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div3><div4><div5><div6><div7>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div8><div9>...
```

OR

```
<div><div1><div2></div>
<div><div3><div4><div5><div6><div7></div>
<div><div8><div9></div>...
```

Placing each line in it's own `<div>` will clear above and below by default

Comment: The extra divs aren't necessary.

Comment: @RickCalder Have you come here just to leave negative comments on answers? No, they are not necessary, but it's an alternative. Your **comments** aren't necessary.

Comment: I could have marked the answer down, but chose not to, it technically works but it's still extra code that isn't necessary. That was what the comment said. Should I give an upvote for what is technically a bad answer? Adding unnecessary code is NOT the answers that should be given, this site is about learning and teaching, if you ask a question do you not want the answer that is the most beneficial? There was nothing negative about my comment, it is just a fact nothing more.

Comment: Who's upvoting the use of extraneous code? Shame. Shame is your name. Consider your 'best practice guru' cards to be revoked.

Comment: -1 Wrapping lines (like your second answer) DOES NOT clear anything. All content following a `float` will continue to jam itself to the right of the preceding content until there is no longer room in the window to do so. `overflow:hidden` can break that effect, but there is no mention of that above.

Comment: Eh this has turned into a child's game, which is why all this upvote downvote crap has issues. Someone downvoted my answer without a reason but I can guess why... you should have to comment if you do either in my opinion, takes the childish games out of it and leaves the correct answers in tact.

Comment: @RickCalder I've read both of your comments, I can see both your points. I can assure you I'm not playing childish games and I agree with your downvoting idea (No, it wasn't me downvoting you!) If I downvote I do it for a reason and try to leave a comment.

Comment: Fair enough. For the record I did not intend for that first comment to be negative honestly. It was just a statement on the answer nothing more. (ps, no downvote either lol)

Comment: @RickCalder OK you get a lot of slander on here from rep-hungry n00bs, I guess it's easy to jump to conclusions, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need extra divs to clear, put clear both on the div that you want to start the next line.

```
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>


.clear{clear:both;}
```

Will put 5 divs in the first line then bump the rest to the second line. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/jQGdv/1/

Comment: I do hope that isn't aimed at me because I'm certainly not the type to downvote out of spite. I've upvoted partly because I like your answer partly to prove that I had not, actually, already voted.

Comment: I deleted the comment, it was childish on my behalf to post it to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

I think wrapping each line in its own `div` would work:

```
<div><div1><div2></div>
<div><div3><div4><div5><div6><div7></div>
<div><div8><div9>...</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is that supposed to do? it's not even valid markup let alone answer any questions.

Comment: To do what? There is no solution there. The markup in the OP's post was for demonstrational purposes not to show the actual markup since that wouldn't display what he's describing

Comment: This would allow OP to achieve the desired result. This is a "simple solution" as requested in the question

Comment: I see what you're doing now after the edit, it's still extra superfluous mark up though. There's no need to add extra divs at all anywhere. A simple class statement on the divs to be bumped down with a clear works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out. I think this will work

```
<div style="clear:left">
  <div1><div2>
</div>
<div style="clear:left"> 
  <div3><div4><div5><div6><div7>
</div>
<div style="clear:left">
  <div8><div9>
</div>
```

Comment: It does work, but there's problems (IMHO): 1) Extraneous-wrapper-block-level elements 2) If one would put that same inline styling onto element 3 and 8, the effect would be the same 3) No need to clear any of the elements prior to the desired effect (`div` #1).